# Flask-Login is_authenticated gives TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable when called

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have the following login view that calls `is_authenticated`.  It works fine on my local machine, but when I install it in production I get `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`.  Why am I getting this error?  Why does it work locally?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(url_for('report'))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

```
File "/home/ubuntu/myapp/app/views.py", line 14, in oauth_authorize
    if not current_user.is_anonymous():
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your User model?

Comment: Just changed `g.user.is_anonymous()` to `g.user.is_anonymous` and it worked